# Insert a modal razor page in the navbar. How to do it?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm building a new website and one of the requirements is to have the login form be a modal window. I'm trying to include it in the top navigation bar and it's only being rendered if the user is not logged in.

How can I add this modal window with it's own model inside the top navbar? Are there any alternatives?

If I delete the model and let an empty modal everything works perfectly but when I add it again it doesn't work, because the model of the page (in this case the index page) is a different one then the one from the modal login.

P.S. I'm using Razor Pages and ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial View**

So you make a `_LoginPartial.cshtml` file. and let's say you set `@model LoginViewModel`

Inside this `_LoginPartial.cshtml` you have your Login Modal and all the functionality.

Now when you invoke your partial inside an `Index` page that has model `@model AnotherModel`, you need to pass a new model to the partial like so:

`<partial name="_LoginPartial" model='new LoginViewModel()' />`

`name` is the name of your `cshtml` page.

`model` is the `@model` of the page.

[Read More Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

**View Components**

To be brief if you take this route this is essentially like nesting a little controller inside your page. Allowing you to change scope for your `@model`.

[Read more about View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

**Update for nested objects**

You need to instantiate the object property.

`<partial name="_LoginPartial" 
           model='new LoginViewModel { InputModel = new InputModel() }' />`

Comment: Which of the options would be the optimal?

Comment: @AndrésGargano For capturing a form partial view. Use View Component when the display is based on some data stored in a database/session some other state.

Comment: Inside my LoginViewModel I have an property of type InputModel (which has 3 properties: email, password and rememberMe) but those are not being mapped to the form and I'm getting "Value cannot be null". Do you know how can this be fixed?