# How to post to a Razor PageModel from partial view?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm building a website which has modal login and registrations forms.

The issue is when I'm trying to submit the form filled by the user, the OnPost of the corresponding razor models are not being called. I also tried using the Identity models as the models for the views and those are not being called as well.

Is there a way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Partial view you need to point the form to the page which has the `OnPost` handle.

```
<form asp-page="/YourPage" method="post">
     ...inputs...
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Make sure your `OnPost` accepts a a parameter of the view model like so:

```
OnPost(MyViewModel vm)
```

Realised you came after this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286289/insert-a-modal-razor-page-in-the-navbar-how-to-do-it/54286817#54286817)

Assuming you have the `LoginViewModel` as a property inside your razor page.

Instead of using

```
<partial name="_LoginPartial" 
      model='new LoginViewModel { InputModel = new InputModel() }' />
```

you want to use

```
<partial name="_LoginPartial" for='LoginViewModel' />
```